# Remove custom tags for AMP page in html string using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, google-amp

I am not that good in writing regular expressions so I am asking for help.

I have html string of my page. I want convert html string to Google AMP compatible page.
In which I want to replace some custom html tags.

```
<define:dos> This string explains DOS.</define:dos>
```

And output should be only `This string explains DOS.`

There are several strings in my html string starting with `<define:` I tried to remove them by writing separate `preg_replace` for each tag which works as expected:

```
$html = preg_replace('#<define:wlan>#i', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('#<define:wifi>#i', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('#<define:dos>#i', '', $html);
```

And so on

I tried something as follows but didn't work :(

```
$html = preg_replace('#\<define[^\]>*\](.*?)\</define\>#m', "$1", $html);
```

I want generic solution for this. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<(define:[^>]+>)(.*?)<\/\1
```

and replace with the second captured group, `\2`.

https://regex101.com/r/wZQBuM/2

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just want to replace tags not content inside it. I need string inside those tags. I have edited my question with expected output.

Comment: See edit, just replace with the second captured group

Comment: It worked for me :) . Thank you. 
I was have one more scenario where I was having only starting of the tag so I resolved it by writing rule <(define:[^>]+>) . Just want to confirm that is this a feasible solution to write it two times ?

Comment: Sure, that looks fine